# MVC 3 navigate to correct ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, actionresult

In my MVC3 project, I have one controller "MyDetailsController" in the

**Areas -> Test -> Controller** Folder

And in From the ActionResult  "Create" in MyDetailsController, I want to call the ActionResult "Edit" of  "DetailsController" Which is located in the **Controller** folder of my application

This is the code I tried

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
//Some Code
return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Details", new { id = Party.PartyID });
}
```

But its not loading the exact ActionResult I need.

The the URL am getting is `http://localhost:53970/Test/Details/Edit/977612`

The URL I needed is `http://localhost:53970/Details/Edit/977612`

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: try return RedirectToAction("Edit", "DetailsController", new { id = Party.PartyID,area="" });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work :

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", "DetailsController", new { id = Party.PartyID ,area = ""});
```